# Elmah.MVC setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I'm trying to get up and running with Elmah for an MVC 5 WebAPI app. All the docs I'm finding seem to start and end with "install it via nuget" and just assume that'll cover it, but I'm clearly missing something. I've installed Elmah.MVC 2.1.1 via nuget, and I am able to view the error log at /elmah. I'm able to request an invalid route and see that the resulting 404 error is getting logged by Elmah, even with customErrors turned on. However, if I generate an unhandled error within a controller, or during controller instantiation, nothing is getting logged to Elmah. For instance:

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/health")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public HttpResponseMessage GetHealth()
{
    throw new Exception("Whoops.");
}
```

I can call this all day long and nothing shows up in the Elmah log. Adding the standard HandleError attribute doesn't change anything, and the little bit of docs [here](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah-mvc) seems pretty explicit that I shouldn't have to create a custom HandleError attribute.

I use Ninject for DI, and similarly if I break a dependency binding I'll get a nice error like this:

```
{
    Message: "An error has occurred."
    ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'HealthController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."
    ...
}
```

But nothing makes it to the Elmah log in that case either.

I assume in both cases this is because MVC is handling those errors for me (formatting the exceptions as JSON, etc) and not passing them on to Elmah. How do I configure things so that any exception not handled within a controller is logged by Elmah?

Comment: Part of your question is useful, but the actual *question* you ask is not a good fit for our site: "Is there a better source of documentation for the current version that I haven't found yet?".  To improve your question and have it re-opened; let us know what you're having a problem with, and how it correlates with the documentation you've used, that way we can point you to an actual answer to your specific problem, instead of a link to documentation (Google is good at the latter, we're good at the former).

Comment: Vote to reopen, OP has edited question to be on-topic.

Comment: If I need to do more to clarify what I'm after, please let me know.

Comment: Haven't had the time to look at this in detail, so I'm not 100% sure, but it may be that the `Elmah.Mvc` package is only for "vanilla" MVC, not for web api - though you should be able to use the main Elmah package. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/16/capturing-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net-web-api-s-with-elmah.aspx

Comment: That gets me halfway there. Looks like the other half is going to be implementing IExceptionLogger (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This is similar to the older ExceptionFilter mechanism, but more global as ExceptionFilters only work with unhandled exceptions from a specific controller and not errors that may crop up higher in the stack. First, I needed a simple ExceptionLogger to pass exceptions to Elmah:

```
public class ElmahExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(context.Exception));
    }
}
```

Then added that in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new ElmahExceptionLogger());
}
```

This does require the latest and greatest MVC/WebAPI (5.1.1 currently).